# Including Static Methods in Companion Objects when Extending from Traits

Tags: scala

I have a trait `Stage`, and various case classes that extend this trait. Each extension of `Stage` has a companion object, like shown below:

```
sealed trait Stage{val: name}
final case class Write(name: String, outputPath: String, overwrite: String) extends Stage
object Write { implicit val fmt = Json.format[Write] }
```

I would like to have every extension of Stage to also implement a static method called `run`. It was my understanding that it is idiomatic in Scala to put all static methods in companion objects, as opposed to in a class itself. Something along the lines of:

```
sealed trait Stage{val: name, def run: String}
final case class Write(name: String, outputPath: String, overwrite: String) extends Stage
object Write {
    implicit val fmt = Json.format[Write] 
    def run: String = {...}
}
```

However, this will (rightly-so) throw an error as the case class `Write` doesn't implement the function `run`. How can I conform to Scala's standard of placing static methods in companion objects in this case? Should I instead just include "run" in the case class like so?

```
final case class Write(name: String, outputPath: String, overwrite: String) extends Stage {
    def run: Dataset = {...}
}
```

Comment: Inheritance does not work with static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companion objects are objects like any other. In particular, they can extend traits as well. So you could have a trait for this secondary behavior.

```
trait Stage { ... }
trait StageCompanion {
  def run(): Unit
}

class Write extends Stage { ... }
object Write extends StageCompanion {
  override def run() = { ... }
}
```

And, of course, in your particular case, such a trait already exists: the Java interface `Runnable`. So you could simply

```
object Write extends Runnable { ... }
```

Comment: Simple way to do what I was asking - hugely appreciate it!